# Prioritise injured cats for treatment (dictionary/map search optimization Python and C++)

Tags: python, c++, performance, hash-map

I am once again attempting another CP problem, and I have ONCE AGAIN run into an optimization issue because of the time limit of one second: https://open.kattis.com/problems/doctorkattis

> It is common for cats to have puncture wounds with different severity
> of infections. To help her local neighbourhood, Doctor Kattis decided
> to open a clinic! However, there are too many injured cats that come
> so she needs to prioritise her patients.
>
> Given the names of N injured cats, their level of severity, and
> subsequent updates of their infection level, determine which cat
> Doctor Kattis needs to give her most attention to.
>
> A cat with higher infection level has higher priority. If there are
> more than one cat with the same infection level, Doctor Kattis will
> give priority to the cat who arrived at the clinic first.
>
> There will be 4 types of commands:
>
> - ArriveAtClinic(catName, infectionLevel): This will be indicated by a    starting integer 0 followed by catName and infectionLevel, e.g. 0
>   LUNA 31. catName is a String that is all UPPERCASE with length 1 to
>   15 characters. The cat names are all unique. infectionLevel is an
>   integer (30≤ infectionLevel ≤100).
> - UpdateInfectionLevel(catName, increaseInfection): This will be    indicated by a starting integer 1 followed by catName and
>   increaseInfection, e.g. 1 LUNA 24. catName is guaranteed to have
>   already arrived at clinic. increaseInfection is an integer (0≤
>   increaseInfection ≤70). The infection level has a maximum value of
>   100 and the update infection commands are given in such a way that
>   the overall infection level of any cat will not exceed 100.
> - Treated(catName): This will be indicated by a starting integer 2    followed by catName, e.g. 2 KITTY. catName is guaranteed to have
>   already arrived at the clinic. catName leaves the clinic after being
>   treated.
> - Query(): This will be indicated by a single integer 3. Your job is to    print the catName with the highest infection level or “The
>   clinic is    empty” if there are no more cats.
>
> **Input:** The first line of input contains an integer N, denoting the number of commands (1≤N≤1000000). There will be up to 200000 cats.
> This will be followed by N commands as described above.
>
> Output Each time the Query() command is encountered, the catName with
> highest infection level or “The clinic is empty” is to be printed in
> one line.
>
> **Subtasks**:
>
> - (30 points): 1≤N≤100, there will be up to 15 cats
> - (30 points): 1≤N≤1000000, there will be up to 200000 cats. However,    there is no call to UpdateInfectionLevel command and the cat with the
>   highest infection level is always the first to be be treated, i.e.
>   you can see this as Treated(Query())
> - (40 points): 1≤N≤1000000, there will be up to 200000 cats. However,    there will be frequent UpdateInfectionLevel commands and the cat with
>   the highest infection level is not always the first to be treated
>
> **Explanation** In the sample test case, we have N=15 commands:
>
> - ArriveAtClinic(“LUNA”, 31)
> - ArriveAtClinic(“NALA”, 55)
> - ArriveAtClinic(“BELLA”, 42)
> - Query(). You have to print out “NALA”,
>   as she is currently the one with the highest infection level.
>   To be precise, at the moment the order is:
>   (NALA, 55), (BELLA, 42), (LUNA, 31).
> - ArriveAtClinic(“KITTY”, 77)
> - Query(). Now you have to print out “KITTY”. The current order is:
>   (KITTY, 77), (NALA, 55), (BELLA, 42), (LUNA, 31).
> - UpdateInfectionLevel(“LUNA”, 24). After this event, the one with the highest infection level is still KITTY with infectionLevel = 77.
>   “LUNA” now has infection level = 31+24 = 55, but this is still 22
>   smaller than “KITTY”. Note that “NALA” also has infection level = 55
>   but “LUNA” is in front of “NALA” because “LUNA” arrived at the clinic
>   earlier. The current order is:
>   (KITTY, 77), (LUNA, 55), (NALA, 55), (BELLA, 42).
> - Treated(“KITTY”). “KITTY” now has been treated ‘instantly’, and    “KITTY” leaves Doctor Kattis’s clinic.
> - Query(). Now you have to print out “LUNA”, as the current order is:
>   (LUNA, 55), (NALA, 55), (BELLA, 42).
> - Treated(“BELLA”). “BELLA” leaves Doctor Kattis’s clinic.
> - Query(). The answer is still: “LUNA”. The current order is:
>   (LUNA, 55), (NALA, 55).
> - Treated(“LUNA”). “LUNA” leaves Doctor Kattis’s clinic.
> - Query(). You have to answer: “NALA”. The current order is:
>   (NALA, 55).
> - Treated(“NALA”). “NALA” leaves Doctor Kattis’s clinic.
> - Query(). You have to answer: “The clinic is empty”.
>
> **Sample Input 1**
>
> ```
> 15
> 0 LUNA 31
> 0 NALA 55
> 0 BELLA 42
> 3
> 0 KITTY 77
> 3
> 1 LUNA 24
> 2 KITTY
> 3
> 2 BELLA
> 3
> 2 LUNA
> 3
> 2 NALA
> 3
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 1**
>
> ```
> NALA
> KITTY
> LUNA
> LUNA
> NALA
> The clinic is empty
> ```

I put each cat into a dictionary/hashmap and set their names to the keys and their infection level as their value. Then I update them in order, delete them when they 'get treated' and return the key with the largest value when they ask a query. This is the fastest solution I can think of, and I'm pretty sure the Python program runs in O(n) time. After my Python program wasn't able to complete it in time, I spent some time translating it into C++, but that also didn't work. I'm not sure if that was because I barely know anything about C++ and I accidentally increased the time complexity with my for loops, or that there's a better solution.

My Python Program:

```
order = {}

n = int(input().strip())
for _ in range(n):
    line = input().strip().split()
    if line[0] == '0':
        order[line[1]] = int(line[2])
    elif line[0] == '1':
        order[line[1]] += int(line[2])
    elif line[0] == '2':
        order.pop(line[1])
    else:
        if len(order) > 0:
            print(max(order, key=order.get))
        else:
            print('The clinic is empty')
```

C++ Attempt:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

pair<string, int> findEntryWithLargestValue(map<string, int> sampleMap){
    pair<string, int> entryWithMaxValue= make_pair("", 0);
    map<string, int>::iterator currentEntry;
    for (currentEntry = sampleMap.begin();
         currentEntry != sampleMap.end();
         ++currentEntry) {
          if (currentEntry->second
            > entryWithMaxValue.second) {
  
            entryWithMaxValue
                = make_pair(
                    currentEntry->first,
                    currentEntry->second);
        }
    }
    return entryWithMaxValue;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    map<string, int> order;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int cmd, inf;
        string name;
        cin >> cmd;
        if (cmd == 0){
            cin >> name >> inf;
            order.insert(pair<string, int>(name, inf));
        }else if (cmd == 1){
            cin >> name >> inf;
            auto check = order.find(name);
            if(check != order.end()){
                check->second += inf;
            }
        }else if (cmd == 2){
            cin >> name;
            order.erase(name);
        }else{
            pair<string, int> query = findEntryWithLargestValue(order);
            if (query.first != ""){
                cout << query.first << '\n';
            }else{
                cout << "The clinic is empty" << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I found another attempt using a heap, but that Python program didn't work either: https://github.com/jed1337/Kattis/blob/master/doctor_kattis.py

> ```
> """
> A heap is used to order the patients by infection level, then arrival time at the clinic
> """
>
>
> import heapq
>
> INFECTION_INDEX = 0
> ARRIVAL_INDEX = 1
> NAME_INDEX = 2
>
> command_count = int(input())
>
> arrive_time = 0
> patient_heap = []
> for _ in range(command_count):
>     command = input().split()
>     opcode = command[0]
>     if opcode == "0":
>         _, name, infection = command
>         # Store the infection in negative so that the most infected will be at the first
>         heapq.heappush(patient_heap, [-int(infection), int(arrive_time), name])
>         arrive_time += 1
>     elif opcode == "1":
>         _, name, increase_value = command
>         for i in range(len(patient_heap)):
>             if patient_heap[i][NAME_INDEX] == name:
>                 patient_heap[i][INFECTION_INDEX] -= int(increase_value)
>                 heapq.heapify(patient_heap)
>                 break
>     elif opcode == "2":
>         _, name = command
>         for i in range(len(patient_heap)):
>             if patient_heap[i][NAME_INDEX] == name:
>                 del patient_heap[i]
>                 heapq.heapify(patient_heap)
>                 break
>     elif opcode == "3":
>         if patient_heap:
>             print(patient_heap[0][NAME_INDEX])
>         else:
>             print("The clinic is empty")
> ```

Am I missing another obvious solution? This probably isn't possible in Python since the [solution statistics](https://open.kattis.com/problems/doctorkattis/statistics) have no Python solutions in them, but there are many solutions in C, C++, Java, Kotlin, and Rust. If there is any way I could speed it up, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Could you clarify what you mean when you say the program "failed"?  If it gives incorrect results, it's not yet ready for review (we require _working_ code here).  If it just takes too long, then replace [programming-challenge] tag with [time-limit-exceeded].  Also, your title should just summarise the _purpose_ of the code (something like "Prioritise injured cats for treatment"?).  Thanks!

Comment: Consider adding `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)` at the start of `main`.

Comment: In the `heapq` documentation, take a look at the sample code under [Priority Queue Implementation Notes](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes).

Comment: "_I found another attempt using a heap, but that Python program didn't work either_" suggests the following code is not your own.  We require code posted here to either be written by (or maintained by) the OP.  We cannot review third-party code.  This should be removed from your question.

Comment: `We can review the C++ code if and only if you wrote that`, we can't review the python solution you found online, and we have to close the question unless you remove the python code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm just reviewing the C++ code here.

## Pass by reference where appropriate

Unlike Python, C++ by default passes parameters by *value*. This means that with your version of `findEntryWithLargestValue()`, a copy of the whole map is made every time you call it. Instead, pass by reference:

```cpp
auto findEntryWithLargestValue(const std::map<string, int>& sampleMap) {
    std::pair<std::string, int> entryWithMaxValue{};
    ...
    return entryWithMaxValue;
}
```

## Use range-`for` where appropriate

Make use of C++'s range-`for` for more concise code:

```cpp
for (auto& currentEntry: sampleMap) {
    if (currentEntry.second > entryWithMaxValue.second) {
        entryWithMaxValue = currentEntry;
    }
}
```

But it can be simplified even further:

## Consider using STL algorithms

The standard library comes with lots of useful [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) that can operate on containers, for example it can find the largest element using [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). Using this, I would remove `findEntryWithLargestValue()` and just write this:

```cpp
auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(order), std::end(order), [](auto &a, auto &b) {
    return a.second < b.second;
};

if (it != order.end()) {
    std::cout << it->first << '\n';
} else {
    std::cout << "The clinic is empty\n";
}
```

## Add an index on infection level

The problem you have is that you have to be able to search both on a cat's name and on its infection level. The `std::map` you created is sorted on name, but to find the cat with the highest infection level, you are doing an expensive \$\mathcal{O}(N)\$ search. You can speed that up if you also have a map of cats sorted by infection level, so that you can find the next cat to treat in \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ time.

Since unlike names, infection levels don't have to be unique, I would create a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) with each element being a `std::pair<string, int>` repesenting a cat, and a custom comparator function that orders by infection level first and name second, like so:

```cpp
static bool compare_by_infection(const std::pair<std::string, int> &a, const std::pair<std::string, int> &b) {
    return a.second != b.second ? a.second < b.second : a.first < b.first;
}

std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>, decltype(compare_by_infection)>
    order_by_infection(compare_by_infection);
```

It's a bit of work (it can be written more compact with recent versions of C++ though), but then looking up the cat with the highest infection level is just:

```cpp
if (order_by_infection.empty()) {
    std::cout << "The clinic is empty\n";
} else {
    std::cout << order_by_infection.back().first << '\n';
}
```

Updating a cat's infection level is now a bit harder though; you have to remove it from `order_by_infection`, then change the level, then add it back.

## Use a `std::unordered_map` to store cats by name

A `std::map` is not the best choice for `order`, as you don't need it to be sorted on name. A `std::unordered` map has faster insertion, removal and lookup (\$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ vs \$\mathcal{O}(\log N)\$ for `std::map`).

## Use `emplace()` instead of `insert()`

Instead of:

```cpp
order.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(name, inf));
```

Write:

```cpp
order.emplace(name, inf);
```

This avoids having to create a temporary `std::pair`, which avoids unnecessary copies.

## Don't use `<bits/stdc++.h>`

[You should not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.](//stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) It is not standard C++. Just `#include` the proper header files, like `<map>`, `<utility>`, `<string>` and `<iostream>`.

Note that also [`using namespace std` is considered bad practice](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721), although it's valid C++. Coding challenge sites often teach you these bad habits, it saves a little bit of typing but it doesn't affect performance, and you might run into problems if you use these shortcuts in real programs.

## Consider creating a `struct Cat`

A `std::pair` is a quick solution to pass two variables at once, but if you use them a lot you'll notice that you have to use `.first` and `.second` everywhere. It would be much clearer if you create a `struct` to group these variables, so you can give them proper names:

```cpp
struct Cat {
    std::string name;
    int infection_level;
};
```

Comment: Some questions, as I'm not much of a C++ guy: Instead of `set<pair<string,int>>` with custom comparator, can't we just use a `multimap<int,string>`? Does `order.emplace(name, inf)` differ from `order[name] = inf`? Both their code and yours order by cat name instead of by which cat arrived first, so aren't both wrong? I'd like to look up the complexity of `set::back` but I can't find it, can you share a link?

Comment: I missed the rule about the arrival order, yes then we're both wrong. I didn't think about `std::multimap`, that's a good suggestion. Then probably the arrival time should also be stored, and then use `equal_range()` followed by a `min_element()`? That might still be slow if you have many cats with equal infection levels...

Answer (score 4):

> This probably isn't possible in Python since the [solution statistics](https://open.kattis.com/problems/doctorkattis/statistics) have no Python solutions in them

Now they do :-)

[image]

Some things about yours:

- Yours isn't \$O(n)\$ but rather \$O(nc)\$, where \$c\$ is the number of cats currently in the clinic. Because your `max(order, key=order.get)` goes through all \$c\$ cats to find the maximum. And \$c\$ can be as large as \$200000\$, so that's a problem.
- You don't need `strip()`, as `split()` takes care of that.
- `max` has a default parameter, so you can just do
  `print(max(order, key=order.get, default='The clinic is empty'))`
  instead of your `if-else`.

Now, how to make it fast enough to get accepted:

- Iterate `sys.stdin` instead of repeating `input()`.
- Organize the cats in a heap.
- Some optimizations.

My solution (accepted in 0.76 seconds, a bit slower but cleaner than my fastest), notes below:

```
import sys, heapq

heap = [(0, 0)]
current = [heap[0]]
indexes = {}
names = ['The clinic is empty']

next(sys.stdin)
for line in sys.stdin:
    command, *args = line.split()
    if command == '0':
        name, level = args
        index = indexes[name] = len(names)
        names.append(name)
        entry = -int(level), index
        current.append(entry)
        heapq.heappush(heap, entry)
    elif command == '1':
        name, increase = args
        index = indexes[name]
        old_level = current[index][0]
        entry = old_level - int(increase), index
        current[index] = entry
        heapq.heappush(heap, entry)
    elif command == '2':
        name, = args
        index = indexes[name]
        current[index] = None
    else:
        while heap[0] is not current[heap[0][1]]:
            heapq.heappop(heap)
        print(names[heap[0][1]])
```

Notes:

- On my **`heap`**, I store pairs of `(negated infection level, cat index)`. Negated level because Python's [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module does *min*-heaps but I want *larger* levels first. And whenever a new cat arrives (command type 0), I give them a new index (1, 2, 3, etc). This ensures proper order among cats with the same infection level and allows fast heap entry comparisons. My **`names`** and **`indexes`** let me look up names and indexes from indexes and names.
- In **`current`** I keep, for every cat, a reference to its *current* heap entry. This allows me to recognize obsolete entries when answering queries (command type 3).
- I use a sentinel<sup>(*)</sup> cat named `'The clinic is empty'` which is perfectly healthy. It'll always be on the heap, so I don't need special checking code to test whether the clinic is empty.
  <sub><sup>(*)</sup> Darn, "feline" and "sentinel" share so many letters, but I couldn't come up with a nice portmanteau.</sub>

Comment: "Hi, this is your cat's veterinary clinic. We're having some computer trouble..."

Comment: @user673679 Oh, dear - Did she break something?

Comment: I am very impressed by the fact that you pulled it off!